# PHP PDO statement passing parameters to LIMIT in a SQL statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, sql, parameters, pdo, int

For some reason, I can't get this to work. It returns the right amount of rows but the data seems to be empty, no matter what I try:

```
$page = intval(trim($_GET['p']));
if($page <= 0)
    $page = 1;
$showcount = 15;
$limit_start = (int)(($page-1)*$showcount);

$stmt_scorelist = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT user_id,min_time 
    FROM scoretable 
    WHERE type_id = :type AND level_id = :level_id 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY MIN(min_time) ASC 
    LIMIT :limit_start, :showcount
");
$stmt_scorelist->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt_scorelist->bindParam(':level_id', $level_id);
$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':limit_start', (int)$limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':showcount', (int)$showcount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I've tried to enter numbers explicitly like this:

```
$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':limit_start', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':showcount', 15, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

It always returns the correct amount of rows, but the data seems to be empty.
I've also tried both (int)$var and intval(trim($var)), I've tried to use bindParam() instead of bindValue(), but none works.

The one thing that works, is if I comment the bound values and replace them with pure numbers in the statement, it works just as intended, the right amount of rows and the data returns:

```
$stmt_scorelist = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT user_id,min_time 
    FROM scoretable 
    WHERE type_id = :type AND level_id = :level_id 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY MIN(min_time) ASC 
    LIMIT 0, 15
");
$stmt_scorelist->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt_scorelist->bindParam(':level_id', $level_id);
//$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':limit_start', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$stmt_scorelist->bindValue(':showcount', 14, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've seen multiple people have the same issues, but none of the solutions they found seems to work for me.

Comment: are you doing `$sth->execute();` ?

Comment: Yep. Like I said, it does return the right amount of rows, it's just that the data seems to be empty

Comment: set `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );`

Comment: Some PDO concerns [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not)

Comment: That actually works, thanks a bunch! Are there any downsides (Performance or security wise) to use that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683576/how-do-i-use-pdos-prepared-statement-for-order-by-and-limit-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```