# PDO order by throws error

Tags: php, pdo

I am confused.

**This is working:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY DATEOFUPLOAD DESC'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
```

**This is not:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY DATEOFUPLOAD :orderbydateofupload'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindValue(':orderbydateofupload', $orderbydateofupload, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->execute();
```

I have checked and set `$orderbydateofupload` by `$orderbydateofupload='DESC'`, so it's definitely not null.

I get an error to the last line (`$stmt->execute()`):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DESC'' at line 1' in /home/gh6534/public_html/query.php:77 Stack trace: #0 /home/gh6534/public_html/query.php(77): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/gh6534/public_html/query.php on line 77
```

I also tried to use the column as parameter:

```
$sort = 'DATEOFUPLOAD';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY :sort :orderbydateofupload'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':sort', $sort);
$stmt->bindParam(':orderbydateofupload', $orderbydateofupload);
$stmt->execute();
```

This does not throw an exception, but all items are queried without any sorting. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$orderbydateofupload = 'ASC';  //Or DESC

if($orderbydateofupload == 'DESC')
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY DATEOFUPLOAD DESC'; 
else
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE'
```

Comment: I guess this question deceived me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683576/how-do-i-use-pdos-prepared-statement-for-order-by-and-limit-clauses

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind identifiers with PDO because **prepared statements can be used only with data**, but not with identifiers or syntax keywords.
So, you have to use *whitelisting*, as shown in the [example I posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587)

That's why in my own class I use identifier placeholder, which makes whole code into one line (when you need to set the order by field only):

```
$data = $db->getAll('SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ?n',$sort);
```

but with keywords whitelisting is the only choice:

```
$order = $db->whiteList($_GET['order'],array('ASC','DESC'),'ASC');
$data  = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ?n ?p", $sort, $order);
```