# PDO LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: php, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO bindValue in LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

I could not display the data when using LIMIT and/or OFFSET in the prepare statement, but I can show "Lei Lei" if I don't use the LIMIT and OFFSET, does the code look wrong?

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM public2 WHERE username = :name LIMIT :sta OFFSET :ppage");
$name = "Lei Lei";
$statement->execute(array(':name' => $name,':sta' => $start,':ppage' => $per_page));
```

This have been change from the original code which worked:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT id,username from public2 LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Any reason you're running `$statement->execute()` twice? And are you using `$statement->fetch()` or `$statement->fetchAll()` after execute to retrieve the results?

Comment: Update my post, I'm using $statement->fetch()

Answer (score 23):

I found the answer!

```
$statement->bindValue(':sta1', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

does work

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why my LIMIT :count wasn't working. It looks like it was being cast as a string.

Answer (score 10):

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

will let you bind variables without being bothered of them type

Comment: why would you even do this when adding PDO::PARAM_INT after the call works?

Comment: This also allows you to use normal array binding rather than doing $statement->bindValue. +1

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Fixed

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM public2 WHERE username = :name LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
$name = "Lei Lei";
$statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
$statement->bindValue(':limit', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':offset', (int) $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: @proyb2 try without the OFFSET like in your original query: `SELECT id, username FROM public2 WHERE username = :name LIMIT $start , $per_page`

Comment: I see, so how can I add the LIMIT into the prepare statement?

Comment: I found the answer! $statement->bindValue(':sta1', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT); does work

Comment: you are wrong. doing this is against the idea of prepared statements

Comment: @Col totally agree, didn't realise LIMIT was supported

Comment: Limit statements certainly can be part of a prepared statement, the values just need to be bound as Integers.

Comment: Hate to necro a thread... but the edited version binds the parameters to the wrong names... 

Given the parameters in the SQL statement "... LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset" you should be binding $start to offset and $per_page to limit