# Using PDO insert values in the limit clause of an SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

In my PDO implementation, I am attempting to use an inserted value in the limit clause of the SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT :limit";
$params = array(":limit" => 5);
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
$result = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$params` and `$query` are correctly returned, but `$result` is empty.

Upon running `print_r($query->errorInfo);`, I get the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1
```

How can I use PDO's insert values in this query? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Are you logging the queries?  What is the actual SQL that is produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PHP PDO bindValue in LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

Basically, you need to cast the limit value to int using intval() when binding.

Comment: Do I have to use bindValue, or is passing in an array of insert values also possible?

Comment: Great! That worked well. It's now in my helper function, so I don't have to do this all the time. Byebye mysql_real_escape_string()!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bind variables into `LIMIT` clause’s operand (exactly, it probably depends on your database system vendor). Instead, use just string interpolation. :-(

```
$limit = 5;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT $limit";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Instead user string interpolation after carefully sanitising the $limit value if you're getting it from outside the system, e.g `$_GET['limit']` or something.

Comment: Unfortunate... However, string interpolation was what I was trying to avoid in the first place!