# MySQL/PDO: Select different columns depending on parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL query that needs to change depending on what parameters are being passed to it. Sounds simply enough, right? The problem is that if the parameter is '0' I need it to grab ALL the records.

How can I do this?

Here's what I have so far.

```
public function getLatestWork($numberOfSlides, $type = 0) {

    $params = array();
    $params["numberOfSlides"] = $numberOfSlides;
    $params["type"] = $type;

    $STH = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT slideID 
        FROM slides
        WHERE visible = 'true'
            AND type = :type
        ORDER BY order
        LIMIT :numberOfSlides;");

    $STH->execute($params);

    $result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    return $result;        
}
```

**Update**: $numberOfSlides is independent of the problem. It will always return a set number of results. *It's all about `$type`:* If it's set to '0' (the default) then it essentially ignores that part of the WHERE statement. If it's set to '1' or '2', etc., then it only pulls records of that type.

Obviously I could just change the value of $STH depending on the value of $type, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`nullif`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and [`ifnull`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) functions:

```sql
SELECT slideID 
FROM slides
WHERE visible = 'true'
    AND ifnull(nullif(:type, 0), type) = type
ORDER BY "order"
LIMIT :numberOfSlides;
```

If `:type` is `0` then `nullif` returns `null`, and if `nullif` returns `null` `ifnull` returns value from `type` column so if you pass `:type = 0`  the result will be `type = type` - means "all rows".

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I've changed my answer, if it's not clear enough, let me know I'll try explain.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Is there any error or sth? ps. it still checks `visible = 'true'` - do you wan to omit as well when `:type = 0`?

Comment: No, that check needs to stay in place. Let me get you the error message.

Comment: "Syntax error or access violation" - check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order LIMIT '20''

Comment: `order` is a restricted keyword, I think? [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Agh. My bad! I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: Yep. I believe that's it. Silly me!

Comment: Still getting an error. Very annoying that it's my SQL to blame, but I don't get this one: "syntax to use near ''20''"

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt it's because of `ORDER BY order`, `order` is a keyword so it's better not to use it as column name or surround it with `"` (I've changed code in answer). Usually it's better to call it `sort` or sth like that.

Comment: @MichałPowaga No, I got that. I've changed it to "priority". That was the NEW error message :-/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I think that `$numberOfSlides` isn't passed as `int`.

Comment: Yep, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getLatestWork($numberOfSlides, $type = 0) {
    $params = array();
    $params["numberOfSlides"] = $numberOfSlides;
    $params["type"] = $type;

    $STH = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT slideIDFROM slides WHERE visible = 'true' "
               . ($type > 0 ? "AND type = :type" : "") 
               . " ORDER BY order LIMIT :numberOfSlides;");

    $STH->execute($params);

    $result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    return $result;        
}
```

Comment: type should be $type. This should run just fine.