# Why is my PDO query using LIKE & LIMIT not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a search box feature that has this query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?";
```

Then in a foreach loop, I make this array:

```
$params[]= "%".$keyword."%";
$params[]= "%".$keyword."%";
```

Then I execute:

```
$stmt=$cxn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

This WORKS, but...

If, after the foreach loop, I want to add " LIMIT ?,?", I do this:

```
$query.=" LIMIT ?, ?";
$params[]=$row_number;
$params[]=$items_per_page;
```

Then I execute the script, and it throws this Fatal Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
 to use near ''0', '2'' at line 1' in ..../index.php:247
  Stack trace:
  #0 .../index.php(247): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
 #1 {main}
 thrown in ..../index.php on line 247
```

I tried to do add apostrophes around the keywords: `$params= "'%".$keyword."%'";`
But this didn't work.

Also, I tried the exact same query inside PHPMyAdmin and it worked.

Does anyone know why this is throwing an error?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$keyword`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO bindValue in LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

Comment: Hi, the value is a string, just letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update:***

```
$query="SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?";
$query.=" LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt=$cxn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%".$keyword."%");
$stmt->bindValue(2, "%".$keyword."%");
$stmt->bindValue(3, $row_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $items_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: sir question, can you mix data types in `PHP` inside array? :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I am trying to figure out how to mix up Bindvalues, along with `?`'s in my code. I got this code from a suggested thread: `$cxn->bindValue(':row_number', (int) trim($row_number), PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @alexx0186 If the previous way does not work, then you need to set the datatype explicitly. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. The datatype was the soruce of the problem. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The reason LIKE isn't working, is because when you use bind parameters with LIKE it's treating '%value%' as a string.

You're going to have to use:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR description LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. The first SQL query in my post does work. The trouble begins when I add the " LIMIT ?,?" at the end of the query. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the variable you have passed in your limit clause. see this `...to use near ''0', '2''` there are single quotes on the values in the `LIMIT` clause

try

```
$query.=" LIMIT ?, ?";
$params[] = intval($row_number);
$params[] = intval($items_per_page);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. I am trying to figure out how I can mix BindValues along with `?`'s. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 why dont you do it like this? one parameter per value (*i mean don't use array*) `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);`

Comment: Hi, the reason I'm not sure I can do it like this, is because I don't know how many keywords the user is gonna type. So with my foreach loop, I just keep adding as many `?`'s as needed (instead of binding values). Not sure I can do this with BindParam..?