# LIMIT using offset error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm loading items with Ajax, and I use an offset

JS:

```
var offset = 0;

$(".load-more").click(function() {
    offset+=5;
    $(this).addClass("spin");
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/fetchitems.php?offset='+offset+'&sort='+sort,
      success: function(data){
        $(".load-more").before(data);
      }
    });
});
```

PHP/SQL:

```
$offset = intval($_GET["offset"]);

$stmt = $db->prepare(
 "SELECT s.id,s.date,s.title,s.views,s.image,s.hidpi,s.width,s.description,u.display_name,u.avatar, s.hotness
  FROM showcase AS s
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT q.id,q.date,q.title,q.views,0,0,0,q.text,u.display_name,u.avatar, q.hotness
  FROM questions AS q
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON q.user_id = u.id
  ORDER BY hotness DESC
  LIMIT :skip, 5
  ");
$stmt->bindParam(":skip",$offset);
$stmt->execute();
$items = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt = null;
```

I'm getting this error at execute:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5', 5' at line 9' in **** Stack trace: #0 **** PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in`

When I run the SQL in phpMyAdmin, it works fine.

Comment: Can you try `$stmt->bindParam(":skip",intval($offset));`?

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853266/pdo-bindparam-not-allowing-statement-to-return-results hope it will help you

Comment: put the  query "SELECT s.id.. to a variable $query and echo $query; exit; Then in the success ajax function alert it or bind it in a div. copy that query and execute in a mysql to see whats wrong in that query. This will help you to rectify your error without any1's help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:skip` gets wrapped in quotes as if it's a string (because the default setting is `PDO::PARAM_STR`), which is wrong, You now get:

```
LIMIT '5',5;
```

According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), you can change a type to int:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":skip",$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The reason this works in your PhpMyAdmin is because you don't add the single quotes.

Comment: according to the docs `PDO::PARAM_STR` is default

Comment: Thanks. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
 "SELECT s.id,s.date,s.title,s.views,s.image,s.hidpi,s.width,s.description,u.display_name,u.avatar, s.hotness
  FROM showcase AS s
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT q.id,q.date,q.title,q.views,0,0,0,q.text,u.display_name,u.avatar, q.hotness
  FROM questions AS q
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON q.user_id = u.id
  ORDER BY hotness DESC
  LIMIT :skip, 5 
  ");

$stmt->bindParam(':skip', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You want to do in this way

Comment: Hi, because you're new I'm not gonna downvote, but: This answer has no added value. It's better to explain *why*  I "want to do it this way" so people can fix similar situation. Apart from that, there is another answer which already explains the problem, your answer doesn't provide more info, or an alternate solution