# When using PDO::bindParam my query returns no results

Tags: php, pdo

I am doing the following query. If i put the numbers straight into the query the query returns lots of results... Now if I use the bindParam to pass the values there are no results.

I've tested whether or not the passed values have values and the echo shows that they do... so I have no idea why this is happening

Could anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
 public function searchWithPagination( $startPage = 0, $numberResultsPerPage = 10 ) {

$q = $this->db->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM ecm LIMIT :startpage, :numberresultsperpage' );
$q->bindParam(':startpage', $startPage);
$q->bindParam(':numberresultsperpage', $numberResultsPerPage);
$q->execute();
echo $numberResultsPerPage . $startPage ;
$f = $q->fetchAll();
var_dump($f);
}
```

EDIT: tried `PDO::PARAM_INT` still doesnt work

Comment: Try bindValue instead. In the user submitted notes in the PHP manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) there is a note about bindParam passing by reference.

Comment: First, PDO::PARAM_INT **[does work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991623/285587)**. Second, [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Comment: @GarethL that made it work! thanks. please post it as an answer

Comment: @GarethL it is not the issue (Unless opening poster didn't provided a **real** code)

Comment: I've posted as an answer, but I agree with @YourCommonSense that probably this is more a workaround than a proper answer. I think you can make it work with bindParam.

Comment: @GarethL What do you mean by real code? thats real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bindValue instead of bindParam. In the user submitted notes in the PHP manual (php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) there is a note about bindParam passing by reference, whereas bindValue doesn't.

Comment: just bindValue didnt work. I also had to include the type cast  (int)$variable for some reason. you might want to change your answer to be fully compliant

Answer (score 0):

The limit parameters has to be bound as integers, the default binding is string.

```
$q->bindParam(':startpage', $startPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam(':numberresultsperpage', $numberResultsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in another question/answer:

[How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit)

You need to bind the params explicitly as INT's, also you should cast them as integers.

```
$q->bindParam(':numberresultsperpage', (int)$numberResultsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I tried that and I get another error saying `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in`

Comment: Another comment there says it depends on the PHP version, i.e. for 5.3 you should use (intval) . Also you should be using bindValue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your question.

In the code that actually runs, you are binding constant values

```
$q->bindParam(':startpage', 0);
$q->bindParam(':numberresultsperpage', 10);
```

which causes the error you mention:

```
Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference
```

But in the code you posted here you are binding variables

```
$q->bindParam(':startpage', $startPage);
$q->bindParam(':numberresultsperpage', $numberResultsPerPage);
```

which works all right, if fed with `PDO::PARAM_INT` or if emulation code is turned off.