# How can I use PHP variable in a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using MySQL and PDO. How can I use PHP variable in this query?

Like this:

```
$startFrom = 0;
$perPage = 12;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $startFrom, $perPage");
$query->execute();
$products = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($products);
```

It works and fetches data when I use normal integers.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0, 10");
$query->execute();
$products = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($products);
```

I tried these, but they didn't work

```
$startFrom = 0;
$perPage = 12;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT ?,?");
$query->execute(array($startFrom, $perPage));
$products = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($products);
```

---

```
$startFrom = 0;
$perPage = 12;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT :startFrom, :perPage");
$query->execute(array("startFrom" => $startFrom, "perPage" => $perPage));
$products = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($products);
```

Comment: Dit you search online? https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php . These are the basics for php pdo.  Please show some effort and at least try to find the answer before asking it here

Comment: This might shed some light on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005593/parametrized-pdo-query-and-limit-clause-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First bind then execute

```
$startFrom = 0;
$perPage = 12;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT ?,?");
$query->bind_param('ii', $startFrom, $perPage);
$query->execute();
$products = $query->fetchAll();
var_dump($products);
```