# bind_param possibly ignoring variable without error

Tags: php, mysqli

I’m experiencing a bizarre issue between PHP and MySQL. I have the following code to get values for an HTML table (`$sortfield` is set to `table1.colb DESC` or `table1.colb ASC`, depending on the test).

```
if (!($stmt = $db_handle->prepare("SELECT table1.cola, table1.colb ORDER BY ? LIMIT ?,20"))) {
    exit('Prepare failed: (' . $db_handle->errno . ') ' . $db_handle->error);
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param('si', $sortfield, $start)) {
    exit('Binding parameters failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    exit('Execute failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
}
$stmt->store_result();
```

This code executes with no errors, but the `ORDER BY` clause is totally ignored when its value is given as a variable. The results are sorted by table1.cola, as if `ORDER BY` were not present. If I replace `ORDER BY ?` with `ORDER BY table1.colb` (and modify `bind_param` accordingly), then the query behaves as expected and sorts by that column.

If I `echo` the complete statement with variables (i.e., `echo "SELECT table1.cola, table1.colb ORDER BY $sortfield LIMIT $start,20"`) and manually run the result directly against MySQL, then the query works as expected.

`$sortfield` is taken from a GET method and processed by `htmlentities()` prior to statement preparation. It’s expected to be a string value, and that’s what it appears to be, so I’m quite confused about the outcome.

Comment: You can't use bind vars for an ORDER BY clause or for LIMIT, only for actual __data values__

Comment: This particular answer is on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/8255054#8255054

Comment: That’s interesting, because the variable binding for `LIMIT` has been in place for several months and has been working without issues. Should it throw an error, or is it simply unsupported? Regardless, I altered the code so only `$sortfield` would be bound, and I got the same result.

Comment: use bindvalue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit

Comment: It actually DOES work for the limit values, but for the order by it will simply order by passed string, which means unordered