# SQL query yields an SQL exception, but running it in the DBMS is error-free?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to execute the following SQL query which is supposed to match up to `5` `users` with a single `mod` whose ID I have retrieved beforehand:

```
$sql =  'INSERT INTO modusergrade (`ModId`, `UserId`)
             SELECT :modId AS ModId, u.Id AS UserId
             FROM users AS u
             LEFT OUTER JOIN modusergrade AS g ON g.UserId = u.Id
             WHERE u.Id NOT IN
                              (SELECT UserId
                               FROM moduserconflicts
                               WHERE ModId = :modId)
             GROUP BY u.Id
             ORDER BY COUNT(g.ModId), rand()
             LIMIT :maxUsers';

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':modId', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':maxUsers', $maxUsers, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

However, executing this yields the following error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "5" at line 11`

Line 11 corresponds to the `LIMIT`, so I'm assuming that there is some kind of issue with `rand()`. Am I supposed to pass it some other way to get an "order randomly" effect?

Comment: Although not quite the same, the solution ended up being the same. I had retrieved `maxUsers` above and forgot to cast it to `int`, and kept on thinking that it surely is one. You can go ahead and submit that as an answer, and I'll gladly accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I'll leave you something tomorrow after my :LIMIT is back as an positiv integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-bindvalue-in-limit) the problem lies within the way pdo handles this parameterized Limit. You need to cast the value to an Integer `(int)` first before binding it.