# PDO prepared statement returning false

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Any idea why this is returning false?

Code using to call function:

```
$product = new Product;
$allProducts = $product->getProducts(12);
```

Function I'm calling:

```
public function getProducts($limit)
    {
        $values = array($limit);
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM sellify_items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?');
        $statement->execute($values);
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Edit: Updated function

```
public function getProducts($limit)
{
    $values = array(intval($limit));
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM sellify_items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?');
    $statement->bindValue(0, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute($values);
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: last time i had it, it was because my `dbname` in DSN was not good, did you checked your connection ?

Comment: Connection works fine. if I remove the $values from the execute, and replace the ? with a number it works fine...

Comment: @Cherryade You might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2269840/3933332

Comment: OH WELL PDO just surround your var with `'` you should use `$stmt->bindValue(0, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note casting to int):

```
$statement->bindValue(0, (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Ended up getting it to work, had to remove the $values.

Comment: @Cherryade aah soz, forgot to tell you to remove `$values` from execute func :') happy this works now :)