# php bind_param for limit

Tags: php, mysql, bindparam

I have problem with binding values to mysql query in php.

```
$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT ? , ? ");
$pageStart = 11; 
$pageEnd = 20 ;
$stmt->bind_param("ii" , $pageStart , $pageEnd );
$stmt->execute();
```

This is returning 20 rows. Any help?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting? Please edit your question with more details!

Comment: You get 20 tows because you tell mysql to get 20 rows after the 11th row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behaviour.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
...
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
...
```

the number after the comma is rowcount.

If you want 10 records, just tell that:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 11 , 10;
```

Comment: Oh thanks I was forgot the parameters. Thank you. Saved my time.

Comment: @manitaz next time you run into something like this, check the documentation first before asking a question.

Comment: for binding the parameters instead of hard-coding them, see also this "trap" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause

Answer (score 2):

> Query is executing correctly. Your parameters having incorrect values as per expected output.

If you want records from `11-20` query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 11 , 10
```

as you are passing 20 as second parameter its returning 20 rows

You can use `LIMIT offset, row_ count` or `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset`

See documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I need to change values dynamically.

Comment: Yes query is executing perfectly. @manitaz you need to change values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`$pageStart = 11;`  Means the result start for 11 and `$pageEnd = 20 ;` means 20 result after 11

So you get 20 result now.

To get result up to 10 you need to set `$pageEnd = 10.` It will return you `result 11 to 21`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the names of your variables you should change

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii" , $pageStart , $pageEnd );
```

to

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii" , $pageStart , $pageEnd - $pageStart + 1);
```

because the second parameter of `LIMIT` is the amount of rows to be selected. The first parameter is the offset.