# $sql="SELECT * FROM billing ORDER BY billing_no limit :go,5";$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);$stmt ->execute(array(':go'=>$go));

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im just trying for pagination in one of my project and I am getting an error like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0',5' at line 1
```

Please Help me..

Comment: post the code in the body not as title

Comment: You bing `go` as a string not as an int

Comment: Read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: Don't bind your limit value. Verify that it's an integer and just pass it in.

Comment: MySql <> Sql Servre.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because $go parameter is being inserted as string rather than int.
I recommend to bind parameters before execute. You can do it like this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':go', $go, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```