# DWL with INNER JOIN doesn't work when LIMIT applied

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple pagination using `Bootpag.js` in order to fetch my data I've created a `PDO` script with an `INNER JOIN` because I need to get and display the user team names from another table also I need to apply `LIMIT` to set the page selection.

This is the troublesome code,

```
session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST["page"])){
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
}else{
    $page_number = 1;
}
$perpage = 3;
//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $perpage);

//Data base join to get team names from teams data base
$getUsers = "SELECT userlogin.*, teams.TeamName FROM userlogin INNER JOIN teams ON teams.tId = userlogin.uTeam ORDER BY uId DESC LIMIT :place, :item_per_page";
$getUsersQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getUsers);
$getUsersQuery -> bindParam(':place', $position);
$getUsersQuery -> bindParam(':item_per_page', $perpage);
$getUsersQuery -> execute();
```

I tried the same SQL in phpMyAdmin it worked with out any errors I don't know why it throwing the below error when used with PHP + PDO.

Note: About the duplicate I've been searching the site using `bindParam` but I didn't see the duplicate and well it really didn't solve my issue the selected answer for this did any way if get marked what

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '3'' at line 1' in ********\fetchUserList.php on line 27

Comment: did you turn  emulation off ? also you need to set the proper param type

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in emulation mode (which is on by default),PDO substitutes placeholders with actual data, instead of sending it separately.PDO treats every parameter as a string. As a result, the prepared LIMIT ?,? query becomes `LIMIT '0', '3'` which is invalid syntax that causes query to fail.

When you using bindParam each variables explicitly you need to set  the proper param type.

you might need to turn off emulation by :

```
$dbConnect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Then

```
<?php

$getUsersQuery -> bindParam(':place', $position,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$getUsersQuery -> bindParam(':item_per_page', $perpage,PDO::PARAM_INT);

?>
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem but I've to delete this 'cos it got marked as a duplicate. I have been searching using `bindparam` not as `bindValue` so didn't see that but some one had the time to search it for me. I didn't know about the emulations part another thing to add.

Comment: its ok, man you may accept the answer, the emulation is turned off just after your connection has been established,

Comment: oh well I can delete another blunder any way thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using limit / offset you need to type caste and pass as integer. Otherwise normally it take it as string

```
$getUsersQuery->bindParam(':place', (int) trim($position), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$getUsersQuery->bindParam(':item_per_page', (int) trim($perpage), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```