# PHP Query Only Working with Variables Inside

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been working on a forum, and now that's it almost done I'm cleaning up my code.

I changed this (which works perfectly):

```
$replyquery = $engine->runQuery("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=:topic_id AND deleted='0' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT $fromRecordNum, $recordsPerPage");
$replyquery->execute(array(':topic_id'=>$thread['id']));
```

To this:

```
$replyquery = $engine->runQuery("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=:topic_id AND deleted='0' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT :recordsNum, :recordsPerPage");
$replyquery->execute(array(':topic_id'=>$thread['id'],':recordsNum'=>$fromRecordNum,':recordsPerPage'=>$recordsPerPage));
```

It seems the second one does not work and throws me an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '10'' at
>   line 1'

Which is weird, because they should technically be both the same, right? Can anyone tell me what is going wrong and how I should resolve this?

Comment: Prepared statements does not support LIMIT (and ORDER BY etc...)

Comment: @DanielO. Would the first query be a security issue, if I left it like that?

Comment: That's not entirely true, @Daniel. You can bind limits and offset.

Comment: @Qirel Maybe it "depends" if you have emulated prepared statements enabled or not. Do you have a working example of that?

Comment: @Daniel Check the flagged dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause :-) You can bind limits/offsets by binding through `bindParam()` instead of through `execute()`, but then all parameters has to be bound through that method. You also have to supply the `PDO::PARAM_INT` parameter.