# What's wrong within SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mariadb

I'm using this query to get range of rows for example 0-5 , But I get an error message.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['per'])){        
    $per = $_GET['per'];
    $pageNumber = $_GET['page'];
    $from = ($pageNumber * $per) - $per;
    $results = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT :sfrom , :sto');
    $results->execute(array('sfrom' => $from , 'sto' => $per));
}
```

I get the following error :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''5' , '5''

I think that's because the `$from` and `$per` are inserted as strings or something I tried to convert them to int using `(int)$from` , `(int)$per`
But still having the same error

Comment: Can you edit your code to include the version with the casting applied? That should resolve it.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause

Comment: @tadman , MYSQL version 4.6.5.2 , It's running on Xampp on my device

Comment: @jack That's not what I was asking about. I mean the version of the code with `(int)` in it.

Comment: @tadman , How can I know the version with the casting applied?

Comment: I've got a simple request here: Can you edit your question to include the casted code? That should work.

Comment: @Strawberry , I edited it ` $results = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT :sfrom , :sto');` but still the same error

Comment: Try `$per = (int) $_GET['per']`and the same for `page`.

Comment: @tadman , I also tried `$results->execute(array('sloc' => $query , 'sfrom' =>(int) $from , 'sto' => (int)$per));` but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

The values passed must be integers but casting them is not enought.

Instruct **PDO** the binded parameters' type is **integer** by using `PDOStatement::`**`bindParam`**

Then call `PDOStatement::`**`execute`** as last step (without parameters).

```
$results = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT :sfrom , :sto');
$results->bindParam(':sfrom', (int)$from, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$results->bindParam(':sto',   (int)$to,   PDO::PARAM_INT );
$results->execute();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$per` and `$from` as numeric strings is totally OK. Make sure you are not passing `"'5'"` as a value. Casting `"'5'"` to `int` results in `0`. Try

```
// remove " and ' then cast to int
$yourNumber = (int) str_replace(['"', "'"], '', $yourInput);
```