# My PDO Prepared Statement is not working with a fetchALL and Limit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to get some products from my database with a prepared PDO statements. The formula worked well if I included the variable inside the SQL but of course this is really bad practice.

Working formula:

```
protected function getSomeProducts($somequantity){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT $somequantity";
        
        $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
```

My approach to the prepared statement:

```
protected function getSomeProducts($somequantity){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT ?";
        
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$somequantity]);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
        
        
    }
```

This is the error message I get:

Fatal error
: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''6'' at line 1.

**Any idea what Im doing wrong could be?**

Comment: i think it might be because you are binding a parameter to the limit clause. have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_COLUMN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the below line

```
$stmt->execute([$somequantity]);
```

with

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $somequantity, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Accept the answer please if it helps you.