# Should you use prepared statments on LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

One day I was googling to understand when a prepared statment should be used. As I searched online many claimed that you should use always prepared statments. Now the question I have is... does this also count for `LIMIT`? I mean it is possible (I tried) but is it really that rational? Same question on `ORDER BY` too.

Comment: You should **always** use prepared statements... when possible, of course.

Comment: alright thanks Impaler!

Comment: Different databases impose restrictions on the location of parameters. For example DB2 does not allow parameters for the LIMIT clause, and you can only use Controlled SQL Injection to implement it. What database are you using?

Comment: I am currently using MySQL

Comment: Best advice: For **any** and **all** values with dynamic data, no exceptions. `LIMIT 1` is fine. `LIMIT $limit` is how you [end up on this list](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: @tadman i love this page, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the database does not allow you to use a parameter on a specific location of the SQL statement you need to assemble the query on the fly, by the use of Dynamic SQL. That is... concatenating strings to get a full functioning SQL query.

Now, the trick is to make it safe against SQL Injection. To do this:

- Make sure the value for `LIMIT` is an integer, and not something unsafe coming right from the UI like `3; DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE`.
- For the `ORDER BY` clause make sure the columns are not coming from the UI "as is"; use some kind of projection. For example, if there are 50 columns to order by, the UI can display them all, but then just send a number (from 1 to 50) to the backend; the backend receives this number and reconstitutes the ordering column(s) from it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the `LIMIT` parameters must be literals, not values that can be substituted for placeholders, so you would have to validate that they're integers before substituting into the string.

However, if you use `PDO` rather than `mysqli`, it allows you to perform parameter substitution in the `LIMIT` clause, by using the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` option. This is automatically enabled for a specific prepared statement if it contains parameters in this clause. See [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit/18063491#18063491) for the specific details.